# TableView - Automatic Scrolling after ViewDidAppear (scrollToRowAtIndexPath)

Tags: xcode, ios7, scroll, tableview

I have a tableview with 2 sections, the first section has 1 row, and the second one has at least 1 (or more) rows.

Now I want the View to load, so that the 1. row of the 1. section is at the top of the screen, but then there should be an automatic 1-row-up-scroll, so that the first cell disappears, and the 1. row of the 2. section is at the atop.

I tried it like this:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

 NSIndexPath *indexPath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:1];
 [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath1 atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

The view appears properly, but the tableview doesn't scroll up.
Thanks for your help guys!

Wusel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like content size of tableView is not large enough to stroll to this cell.

Try to play with contentOffset property to scroll tableView to correct position manually. 
I believe it should help.

Comment: Do you mean, that the scroll is not executed, because the cell is already on the screen, so a scroll is technically not required?